How to properly setup Azure connectivity from App service to Storageaccount?
I have this situation:
We have publicly available app service with public internet access and I have blob storage with images. I need to have this app publicly accesible, but blob storage should be private. I've tried to implement it via privatelink and enabled vNet integration for App service Outbound traffic configuration with subnet.
So, I have this subnet 10.0.3.0/24 for app service. For privatelink I am using another one 10.0.1.0/24. But they are in the same vNet. For storageaccount I also enabled access restrictions to allow access only from my vNet. But when I am using privatelink, I am receiving when connecting from public application net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED (from app service machine I can resolve this name).
If I am using Service Endpoint without private link and storageaccount limited with access only from vNet, I am receiving Forbidden (after disabling vNet access and making blob public I can access it). I assume that it connects with my Client Public IP instead of vNet ip from app service and only one solution is to whitelist every IP in firewall.
So, the question is - what I've done wrong and is that possible to implement this architecture? As I moved from AWS and currently this Azure magic is a little bit complicated for me :)
Also they are in the same subscription

check with this once https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/app-service-to-storage-account-connection-condition-summary/ba-p/2968642 @andrewstriletskyi

Hi. Yes, I already checked it. But in this doc specified that app service will use private ip to connect to storageaccount (from logs). In my case, I created test app service with Flask application which loads images. But in logs I see that It's using my public ip and I can't access blob

When I am using private link with public app, I am receiving net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED to this storageaccount

Also 1 note: noticed that upload from app is working, list - no:
https://github.com/AndrewKarpaty/flask-azure-app/blob/main/app.py

Also noticed from logs that ListBlob, and PutBlob requests are using private ip and It's working fine, but GetBlob is using my client IP from browser

Can you please share the result of nslookup  from app service.


How to properly setup Azure connectivity from App service to Storage account?

If you use a service endpoint to establish the connection between an App Service and a storage account, make sure to add Microsoft.Storage under Service Endpoints in the subnet where your App Service is integrated. Then, configure the storage account firewall and select the subnet where your App Service is located.

Here is the result of service endpoint.

If you are using a private endpoint, create a private endpoint for the storage account and disable public network access under Firewalls and virtual networks.

A private DNS zone will be created automatically with the private endpoint.

Once you have created the private DNS zone, check that the VNet is linked to the DNS zone, as shown below

After creating the private endpoint, the App Service will be able to resolve the storage account endpoint with the private endpoint IP.

The Service endpoint and Private endpoint are correct approach in point of security. But you can choose the service as per requirement, for simpler setup with less cost go for Service Endpoints, whereas private endpoint has more security and privacy.
Reference: Connect to a storage account using an Azure Private Endpoint
